# How to log all selenium http requests?

Tags: selenium, logging

I am using Selenium for a unit test and once and a while during the unit test one of the requests goes COMPLETELY WILD and makes like 1000 requests to the server in under an hour.

This is just an unfortunate bug in my selenium script but it's hard to reproduce.

Is there some way I can log all the HTTP client requests being made from Selenium driver? I'm using the Chrome driver in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend installing Fiddler to log the HTTP requests.

http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Answer (score 1):

Try using BrowserMob proxy. You can integrate through your selenium and log all your requests as Har and analyse them.