# Selenium, Intercept HTTP Request?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Using selenium 4.12 in Python, how can I intercept an HTTP request to see what its body or headers look like?

Please Note, that I'm not asking for code but rather for resources/ideas of different or suggested methods to do so. As most of the resources refer to old versions of Selenium and I read a lot has changed in relation to this task in version 4.

I know there is the option to turn on wireshark but is there something to do with Python or Selenium itself?

**Please Note:** I have written a huge number of lines using selenium so I prefer a method in which I don't need to fully rewrite my code or with minimal effort.

Comment: Hi everyone, I found a possible solution but it's not working for me to test it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77063407/selenium-python-wrong-imports

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to log all selenium http requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459594/how-to-log-all-selenium-http-requests)

Comment: @SepuLing it's from 2015... have u read my question?

Answer (score 1):

If you need just to get request / response data without modifying it, Selenium 4 has a feature that logs network events.

You just need to enable capability `'goog:loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'}` and then call `driver.get_log("performance")` when you expect that needed request was performed.

To get event data, you can execute commands from [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-getResponseBody).

For example, this code gets response body for defined request with url part.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import json

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.set_capability('goog:loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('url')

logs = driver.get_log("performance")

target_url = 'your_target_url_part'

for log in logs:
        message = log["message"]
        if "Network.responseReceived" in message:
            params = json.loads(message)["message"].get("params")
            if params:
                response = params.get("response")
                if response:
                    if response and target_url in response["url"]:
                        body = driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.getResponseBody', {'requestId': params["requestId"]})
                        response_body = body['body']
```

Example of usage:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import json
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()


options.set_capability('goog:loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'})
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://google.com")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
text_area = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'textarea[class]')))
action_chains = ActionChains(driver)
action_chains.click(text_area).perform()
search_input = 'Network Interceptor'
# this block is written to emulate user typing, so it would be sent each search request per letter
for i in range(len(search_input)):
    action_chains.send_keys(search_input[i]).perform()
    time.sleep(0.3)
target_url = 'search'
logs = driver.get_log("performance")

def get_search_repsonses():
    for log in logs:
        message = log["message"]
        if "Network.responseReceived" in message:
            params = json.loads(message)["message"].get("params")
            if params:
                response = params.get("response")
                if response:
                    if response and target_url in response["url"]:
                        body = driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.getResponseBody', {'requestId': params["requestId"]})
                        print(body)
                        print('____________________________________________')

get_search_repsonses()
```

Comment: your come missing imports and doesn't run

Comment: @Dan added imports. I thought they are trivial. :)

Comment: It crashes always, can you give full working example with url and target url? what if I want to catch all requests from the moment I opened the driver till closed?

Comment: I added example of usage. If you want to get all requests, you should remove if condition that checking `target_url` and observe `Network.requestWiiBeSent` or `Network.responseReceived` (depends on what data do you need to observe).
I provided a link to Dev Tools Protocol API in my answer.