# How to get image response in chrome devtools using python webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to make a python code that automatically receives images from web pages.

The method is to get image response that can be obtained by accessing a specific web page using Selenium and copying the data of the image from the network of chrome devtool.

This is because specific sites are blocked by cloudflare, and if I use common methods such as requests or urllib.request, 403 errors occurred.

I can receive image data through 'Copy response' like a screenshot, but I want to get it using the chrome webdriver with python.

[Copy response in Chrome devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQrWW.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.set_capability('goog:loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'})
option.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)

browser.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

log_entries = browser.get_log("performance")
```

I got response header with above code but I want to get full response of images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get responses, you should loop through logs and filter `message` object by message that contain event `Network.responseReceived`.

Then you get `params` object and check if target_url_part is present in `url`.

After getting it, you execute CDP command `Network.getResponseBody` with `requestId` from params.

Depends on response body, you can perform further actions, like getting it's json field / convert it into image, etc.

[Similar question answer reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77065745/20292589)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import json
import time

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.set_capability('goog:loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'})
option.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
log_entries = browser.get_log("performance")

url = 'site_url'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
target_url = "your_request_url_part"

for log in log_entries:
    message = log["message"]
    if "Network.responseReceived" not in message:
        continue
    params = json.loads(message)["message"].get("params")
    if params is None:
        continue
    response = params.get("response")
    if response is None or target_url not in response["url"]:
        continue
    body = browser.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.getResponseBody', {'requestId': params["requestId"]})
```

Comment: multiple nesting of if stantements is poor practice. write the same in logical flow or using breaks....

Comment: @D.L does updated snippet look better for you now?

Comment: `log_entries` is not defined (presumably a list ?). `json` is not defined (presumably imported module).  And `driver`... what is this ?   ...but, yes.  the format is better :)

Comment: @D.L well, I thought it is understandable from code of topic starter, I just added missed part. However, if it is not - I added imports. :)

Comment: i think you ment `browser.execute_cdp_cmd` and not `driver.execute_cdp_cmd`...

Comment: Yep, thanks for pointing. As you understood, that is just code prototype. In my local code that variable is named as `driver`

Comment: Thank you for all the comments.  The example code works well!